# Nested loops not outputting correctly

Tags: java, loops, nested-loops

For the lab I'm currently working on it gives me this as an aid:

```
output = ""
output += word

loop i that runs 
{
output += word.charAt(i)

loop j
{    
  output += " "

}

output += word.charAt( ______ )+ "\n"
}

StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(word);

output += word backwards
```

Here's my code as it is now:

```
import static java.lang.System.*;

class BoxWord
{
 private String word;

public BoxWord()
{
    word="";
}

public BoxWord(String s)
{
    word = s;
}

public void setWord(String w)
{
    word = w;
}

public String toString()
{
    String output="";
    output += word + "\n";
    for(int i =1; i<word.length(); i++)
    {
        output += word.charAt(i);
        for(int j =i+1; j<word.length()-i; j++)
        {
            output += " ";
        }
        output += word.charAt((word.length()-i)) + "\n";
    }
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(word);
    output += sb;
            
    return output+"\n";
}
}
```

Here's my runner class for cross-referencing:

```
import static java.lang.System.*;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab11f
{
 public static void main( String args[] )
   {
   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String choice="";
        do{
            out.print("Enter the word for the box : ");
            String value = keyboard.next();
            

                //instantiate a BoxWord object
         BoxWord bw = new BoxWord(value );
            //call the toString method to print the triangle
            System.out.println( bw );

            System.out.print("Do you want to enter more data? ");
            choice=keyboard.next();
        }while(choice.equals("Y")||choice.equals("y"));
}
}
```

currently it is outputting like this:

> square
>
> q   e
>
> u r
>
> aa
>
> ru
>
> eq
>
> square

when it needs to be like this:

> SQUARE
>
> Q>>>>R
>
> U>>>>A
>
> A>>>>U
>
> R>>>>Q
>
> ERAUQS
> (where a ">" represents a blank space, the last column should be aligned btw)

here's a link to a google docs version of the labsheet: https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B_ifaCiEZgtcVTAtT2t0ajRPLUE

**UPDATE**:

Ok, that's working for the most part. I'm getting this now:

> square
>
> q>>>>e
>
> u>>>>r
>
> a>>>>a
>
> r>>>>u
>
> e>>>>q
>
> square

**UPDATE #2**
Now my result is like this:

> square
>
> q>>>>e
>
> u>>>>r
>
> a>>>>a
>
> r>>>>u
>
> erauqs

Comment: That doesn't seem to contain a question.

Comment: my question is what is causing it to not output properly, the issue is more properly addressed at the bottom if you see what it is outputting currently versus what it should be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Problem is in the second Loop. You want to add spaces equal to the `word.length - 2`.

```
for(int j = 0; j < word.length()-2; j++)
{
     output += " ";
}
```

instead of

```
for(int j =i+1; j<word.length()-i; j++)
{
     output += " ";
}
```

**Edit:** 
Did not see that you got e to much. and the bottom square was not reversed.

```
for(int i =1; i<word.length()-1; i++) // -1 so the last letter is not added
{
    output += word.charAt(i);
    for(int j =i+1; j<word.length()-i; j++)
    {
        output += " ";
    }
    output += word.charAt((word.length()-i-1)) + "\n";
}
```

For reversing the String you have to use `StringBuffer.reverse()`

```
output += sb.reverse();
```

Comment: Check my update above, most of the issue is resolved but the bottom "square" needs to be "erauqs" and the left instance needs to be backwards as well but vertically

Comment: in addition to the e from the left vertical needs to be applied to the backwards bottom word

Comment: @tech_geek23 Hint: how does the position (in the word) of the letter at the right border change from one line to the next?

Comment: did you intend on not changing the parts of the code in your edit or do I apply what was said in your original answer as well?

Comment: I've updated my results in my OP and it looks as though everything is correct except a missing "q" from the right side reversed vertical word and a double "e" on the same word

Comment: added a -1 at the line output += word.charAt((word.length()-i))

Comment: Thanks for all your help! Sorry for a long delay at one point.... was dealing with college scholarship acceptance stuff